# Responsive UI in React Native using metrics directly from the design

Tags: javascript, react-native, responsive-design

I'm trying to get the perfect safe area outside of the top and bottom areas of a mobile device, like below.

[image]

My goal is to put the designer's value into a function and quickly have a screen that will look exactly the same on both Android and iOS. There are packages, but unfortunately, they do not work perfectly. There are always differences between Android and iOS or between Android models. To fix this situation, I did something like this:

1. For example, suppose the designer has placed two buttons with 426 and 420 sizes on a green screen with default dimensions of 393x852. So a green area of 6 units will appear at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

2. In such a case, I prepared a function like the one below to take the number directly from the design and transfer it directly to the code. The general logic is this: On phones and tablets with a notch, the value of "Dimensions.get("window").height includes the safe area as well as the height in its upper (status bar) and lower fields. Therefore, we subtract these two fields. On handset phones without a notch, only the top field is included in the "Dimensions.get("window").height" value. Therefore, we only remove the upper part. I may have misdiagnosed this situation. I came to this conclusion based on the devices I tried. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView, initialWindowMetrics } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'

const MainScreen = () => {

    const defaultValues = {
        height: 852,
        width: 393
    }

    const units = {
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
        height: Dimensions.get("window").height - initialWindowMetrics.insets.top - (DeviceInfo.hasNotch() || DeviceInfo.getDeviceType() == "Tablet" ? initialWindowMetrics.insets.bottom : 0)
    }

    const getRH = (number) => {
        return (number * units.height) / defaultValues.height
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}  >
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "green" }} >
                <View style={{ height: getRH(426), backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9" }} />
                <View style={{ height: getRH(420), backgroundColor: "#835050" }} />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>

    );
};

export default MainScreen;
```

3. As a result, everything works fine on the emulators shown in the screenshot below as well as on the physical devices: Sony Xperia XZ1 (no notch handset), Samsung Galaxy A7 2018 (no notch handset) and iPhone 8 (no notch handset).

[image]

Problem: When I try this procedure on the Reeder P13 Blue Max L 2022 device, a problem occurs. Because "Dimensions.get("window").height" directly returns the safe area (not including the top and bottom areas) as a value. As a result, the green part looks much more in the function I prepared.

Question: How can I resolve these different behaviors? As I mentioned above, my goal is to quickly prepare a UI that gives the same result on all devices by putting the value given by the designer into a function. How can I reach this conclusion?